# Explain this Graph Matching solved in Linear Time

Tags: assignment-problem

I'm interested in a better explanation about the paper [Computing Optimal Assignments in Linear Time for Approximate Graph Matching](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.10356.pdf).

The graph edit distance is approximated  by assignments in linear time.

Briefly speaking there is an embedding of optimal assignment costs into a Manhattan metric: $φ_c(A) = [A_{uv}^← · w(uv)]_{uv∈E(T)}$. The Manhattan distance between these vectors is equal to the optimal assignment costs between the sets.

The problem is: it is not throughly explained how I find $A_{uv}^←$ and how I use Weisfeiler-Lehman to label the vertices of a tree in the following figure:

[image]

Please, explain how I find $A_{uv}^←$ and how I label that tree.